# How can left-factoring eliminate backtracking while there are non-terminals?

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to implement a parser generator (for fun), following the book [Engineering a Compiler](https://shop.elsevier.com/books/engineering-a-compiler/cooper/978-0-12-815412-0). The book suggests left-factoring for eliminating backtracking:

```
A -> B m | B n | m
B -> m
```

Becomes:

```
A -> B A' | m
B -> m
A' -> m | n
```

But now, `B` starts with `m`, `A'` starts with `m`, and `A` has a production alternative that also starts with `m`, hence the [start sets](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/%7Ecs331/notes/FirstFollow.pdf) for `A`, `B` and `A'` have the common element `m`, disqualifying the grammar for a LL(1) parser.

Is the grammar above inherently a non-backtrack free grammar and requires a more powerful parser such as a LR(1) parser? Or am I applying the left-factoring wrong? or there needs to be a prior step to left factoring so that no rule starts with a non-terminal (is it even possible?)

I feel the book is missing some description, in lot of places and this is one example.

---

In the above grammar, I simplified the issue I'm facing with the following toy grammar:

```
start           -> fn_declaration start | fn_declaration |
fn_call         -> ID ( args ) ;
args            -> args , arg | arg |
arg             -> STR | INT | ID
fn_declaration  -> FN ID ( params ) { statements }
params          -> param , params | param |
param           -> ID ID
statements      -> statement , statements | statement |
statement       -> declaration | assignment | fn_call | ret
declaration     -> ID ID ;
assignment      -> ID = expressions ;
expressions     -> terms + expressions | terms - expressions | terms
terms           -> factor * terms | factor / terms | factor
factor          -> ( expressions ) | INT | ID
ret             -> RETURN expressions ;
```

To which I'm applying these steps, in this order:

- Eliminate epsilons.
- Eliminate left recursion.
- Eliminate backtracking (by left-factoring).
- Calculate first and follow sets.

All steps do their job, but I eventually have these rules:

```
statement => alt=[ declaration | assignment | ret | Id ( statement_p0 ], first=[Id, return, ;], follow=[,, }]
statement_p0 => alts=[ args ) ; | ) ;], first=[), Int, Str, Id], follow=[,, }]

# ...rest of the rules removed for brevity
```

`declaration` and `assignment` share `ID` as their first token kind, and fail the is-backtrack-free test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to left-factor the grammar, you need to ensure that every symbol that begins the RHS of a rule for some non-terminal has a disjoint FIRST set from every other symbol.  The easiest way to do that is to first left-expand the grammar -- expand every initial non-terminal symbol on a RHS so that the RHS of every rule begins with a terminal.

When you do that you get

```
A -> m m | m n | m
B -> m
```

so now you left-factor the A rules to

```
A -> m A'
A' -> m | n | ε
```